# Basic copying of Linked List to another LinkedList

Tags: python, linked-list, nodes

Okay so I am new to computer programming and to make a long story short I don't want to be a grocer for the rest of my life. I am 25 and just learning these concepts and python along with that so please be kind.

I want to copy a linked list from a LinkedList object to another using a function called copyList. It should take no parameters other than its self and it should output a copy of the LinkedList while not altering the original list.

I tried looking onto the stack and found a similar code but it did not solve my issue for the code is similar to mine but does not work in that I try printing the new LinkedList and it does not contain the values and is empty I believe. I provided the similar code in the code below commented out:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.data = x
        self.next = None
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.top = None
    def printList(self):
        print("top^")
        while self.top is not None:
            print(self.top.data)
            self.top = self.top.next
        print("tail^")
    def in_list(self, x):
        current = self.top 
        while current is not None:
            if current.data is x:
                return 1
            current = current.next
        return 0
    def findCellBefore(self, x):
        current = self.top
        if current is None:
            return 0
        while current.next is not None:
            if current.next.data is x:
                current = current.next
        return 1
    def findCellBeforeSential(self,x):
        if (self.top.next is None):
            return 0 
        while (self.top.next is not None):
            if (self.top.next.data is x):
                return self.top.data
        return 1
    def add_0(self, newNode):
        # i. make next of new node as head.
        newNode.next = self.top
        # ii. move head to point to new node.
        self.top = newNode
    def add_end(self, newNode):
        current = self.top
        if (current is None):
            self.add_0(newNode)
            return 
        while (current.next is not None):
            current = current.next

        current.next = newNode 
        newNode.next = None
    def insertNode(self, after_me, new_cell):
        new_cell.next = after_me.next 
        after_me.next = new_cell

        # update prev links.

        new_cell.next.prev = new_cell 
        new_cell.prev = after_me 
    def  deleteAfter(self, after_me):
            after_me.next = after_me.next.next

    def CopyList(self):#Out put new Linked List that is a copy of current Linked List with out altering it. 
        # create new LinkedList
        newLinkedList = LinkedList()
        #current = self.top
        #below is from stackoverflow : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491307/how-to-copy-linked-list-in-python
        #while current.next != None:
        #    newLinkedList.add_end(current.data)
        #    current = current.next
        #newLinkedList.add_end(current.data)
        #return newLinkedList
        while self.top is not None:
            newNode = Node(self.top.data)
            newLinkedList.add_end(newNode)
            self.top = self.top.next
        return newLinkedList

LIST0 = LinkedList()

node0 = Node(1)
node1 = Node(2)
node2 = Node(3)
LIST0.add_end(node1)
LIST0.add_0(node0)
LIST0.add_0(node2)
node3 = Node(4)
LIST0.insertNode(node2, node3)

LIST0.printList()

LIST1=LIST0.CopyList()

LIST1.printList()
```

I want it to simply print out the new list that is a copy of LIST0 and have LIST1 work as a LinkedList object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through your code it appears that @John Bayko is correct in that you must leave self.top(head sentinel) alone so... in your code it appears that you have certain functions that use self.top out right and others that use current= self.top to reference to it and do the respective work within the function. **The top pointer of a function should be exactly that in that it should be a reference** (*universally - think of it as the "northern star" for you to follow as your guide as your navigate your list*) for the rest of your code to follow.

Below is the code corrected: After this understanding linked list and other concepts should flow more easier.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.data = x
        self.next = None
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.top = None
    def printList(self):
        print("top^")
        current = self.top
        while current is not None:
            print(current.data)
            current = current.next
        print("tail^")
    def in_list(self, x):
        current = self.top 
        while current is not None:
            if current.data is x:
                return 1
            current = current.next
        return 0
    def findCellBefore(self, x):
        current = self.top
        if current is None:
            return 0
        while current.next is not None:
            if current.next.data is x:
                current = current.next
        return 1
    def findCellBeforeSential(self,x):
        current = self.top
        if (current.next is None):
            return 0 
        while (current.next is not None):
            if (current.next.data is x):
                return current.data
        return 1
    def add_0(self, newNode):
        # i. make next of new node as head.
        newNode.next = self.top
        # ii. move head to point to new node.
        self.top = newNode
    def add_end(self, newNode):
        current = self.top
        if (current is None):
            self.add_0(newNode)
            return 
        while (current.next is not None):
            current = current.next

        current.next = newNode 
        newNode.next = None
    def insertNode(self, after_me, new_cell):
        new_cell.next = after_me.next 
        after_me.next = new_cell

        # update prev links.

        new_cell.next.prev = new_cell 
        new_cell.prev = after_me 
    def  deleteAfter(self, after_me):
            after_me.next = after_me.next.next

    def CopyList(self):#Out put new Linked List that is a copy of current Linked List with out altering it. 
        # create new LinkedList
        newLinkedList = LinkedList()
        current = self.top
        #below is from stackoverflow : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491307/how-to-copy-linked-list-in-python
        while current is not None:
            newNode = Node(current.data)
            newLinkedList.add_end(newNode)
            current = current.next
        return newLinkedList
        print("here")

        #current = self.top
        #print(current)
        #while current.next is not None:
        #    print(0)
        #    newNode = Node(self.top.data)
        #    print(1)
        #    newLinkedList.add_end(newNode)
        #    print(2)
        #    self.top = self.top.next
        return newLinkedList

LIST0 = LinkedList()

node0 = Node(1)
node1 = Node(2)
node2 = Node(3)
LIST0.add_end(node1)
LIST0.add_0(node0)
LIST0.add_0(node2)
node3 = Node(4)
LIST0.insertNode(node2, node3)

LIST0.printList()

LIST1=LIST0.CopyList()

LIST1.printList()
```

Answer (score 1):

A big part of the problem is this:

```
while self.top is not None:
    newNode = Node(self.top.data)
    newLinkedList.add_end(newNode)
    self.top = self.top.next
```

Normally self.top points to the top of the nodes, and should not change unless the top node is replaced or deleted. What you're doing here is basically removing all the nodes from your list.

The commented out code looks correct, except that the line "newLinkedList.add_end(current.data)" is not indented enough. One of the complaints of Python's indentation system is that if code is pasted in a way that changes indentation, that also changes the grouping of the lines. That line should be part of the loop and match the indentation of the lines above it.

Comment: @Cameron Carter you're right, the commented out code had other problems than indentation, I didn't look at it closely enough.